# The height and width of the near plane in perspective projection

Tags: qt, opengl

I use a 45.0 fov degree for my perspective projection so the distance of camera to the near plane equals the height of the near plane but It seems that the near plane height is bigger than I expected and it is a contradiction to the geometry. My objects on the near plane overflow from window. I use shaders to apply matrixes and  did not use any glViewport. should I use glViewport?

Comment: Qt.   ( QMatrix4x4::perspective)

Comment: m_pMatrix.perspective(45.0f, float ( width ) / height, 200, 200)

Comment: "and did not use any glViewport". The GL viewport is a _state_, it always has some values. Initially, it will match the whole output window when you make current the GL context the first time. There is not necessarily a need to ever change that as long as your window size doesn't change. However, it is totally unclear why you ask about the viewport as this does not define  the view frustum in any way.

Comment: Try setting the perspective's aspect ratio to 1.